# How to get the value of Template Layout File of product using handlebars on bigcommerce stencil theme?

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I want to get the value of "Template Layout File" in my product template. Based on this value, I have to print different values for the products.

I tried to get the value like this:
{{product.template_layout_file}}

I did not get any output.

As reference, kindly see the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A product's template layout file can be accessed in Handlebars with {{template}} while you're on that product's display page, note that "product" should be excluded since the template object isn't a subresource. [Find more info about the template object on the dev docs here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/global-objects-and-properties#template-property).